# How to start with OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, design-patterns

i've been learning Javascript like for 8 months right now, 5 months ago i found job as a Front End developer and i've been getting envolved more deeply in javascript, that's a thing I love. Recently I noticed that my code looks so ugly because were a bunch of functions and global variables, so I started reading a little bit about design patterns. Now i come with something is working for me but I am not sure if is a good practice, anyway i would like you guys to take a look on the code and tell me what can I improve and what is the better way to star using modular pattern in javascript, also if you can suggest me some material to learn about modular pattern and Javascript.

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var responsiveModule = {

    settings: {
        device: false,
        button: $(".responsive-btn"),
        target: $("nav ul"),
        mobileClass: "toggle-menu",
        bgImage: '<img class="background-image" src="img/background.jpg" alt="">',
        bgImageSelector: $(".background-image"),
        windowWidth: $(window).width(),

    },

    init: function(){
        responsiveModule.checkDevice();
        responsiveModule.replaceImages();
        responsiveModule.bindFunctions();
        responsiveModule.listenResize();
    },

    checkDevice: function(){
        if(this.settings.windowWidth > 992){
            this.settings.device = "desktop";

        } else {
            this.settings.device = "mobile";
        }
    },

    bindFunctions: function(){
        var buton = this.settings.button,
            muelleBtn = this.settings.muelleBtn;
        buton.on("click touchstart", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            responsiveModule.animateMenu(responsiveModule.settings);
        });
    },

    animateMenu: function(settings){
        var device = settings.device,
            target = settings.target,
            mobileAnimation = settings. mobileClass;

        if(device == "mobile"){
            target.toggleClass(mobileAnimation);
        }
    },

    replaceImages: function(){
        var bgContainer = $("#main-content"),
            bgImage = responsiveModule.settings.bgImage,
            device = responsiveModule.settings.device,
            backgroundSelector = $(".background-image");

        if(device == "desktop" && backgroundSelector.length == 0){
            bgContainer.append(bgImage);
        }else if(device == "mobile" && backgroundSelector.length == 1){
            backgroundSelector.remove();
        }
    },

    listenResize: function(){
        $(window).on("resize", function(){
            responsiveModule.checkDevice();
            responsiveModule.replaceImages();
            responsiveModule.settings.windowWidth = $(window).width();
        });
    }


}

var tooltipModule = {

    settings: {
        tooltipState: false
    },

    init: function(){
        tooltipModule.bindUIfunctions();
    },

    bindUIfunctions: function(){
        var device = responsiveModule.settings.device;
        if(device == "mobile"){
            $(".ship").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                tooltipModule.manageTooltip(e);
            });
        }else{
            $(".muelle-item").addClass("desktop");
        }
    },

    manageTooltip: function(e){
        var tooltip = $(e.currentTarget).next(),
            tooltips = $(".tooltip");

        tooltips.removeClass("display");
        tooltip.addClass("display");
    }


}


$(document).on("ready", function(){
    responsiveModule.init();
    tooltipModule.init();   
});
```

Comment: Stack Overflow has a sister site dedicated entirely to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I suggest you post this question in it, as it's more on topic there.

Comment: I will follow your suggestion, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not so bad. However I don't like that you use Singletons. It's good that you separated responsiveModule and tooltipModule, but I'll suggest to use the revealing module pattern (it's kinda favorite for me):

```
var ResponsiveModule = function() {

    var settings = {
        // ...
    };

    var init = function() {
        checkDevice();
        replaceImages();
        bindFunctions();
        listenResize();
    }
    var checkDevice = function() {}
    var bindFunctions = function() {}
    var animateMenu = function() {}
    var replaceImages = function() {}
    var listenResize = function() {}

    return {
        init: init
    }

}

var responsiveModule = ResponsiveModule();
responsiveModule.init();
```

You are able to create as many instances as you want from that module. And you have private scope.

That's one of the best books for design patterns in javascript:
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Here are few toughts from me about JavaScript:
http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/JavaScript-is-cool-modular-programming-extending

Comment: Hey! I will read the book and also going to add your blog to my bookmarks thank you for answering so fast. When you talk about create a new instance of my module you refer to the use of prototype or just using something like var responsiveModule2 = ResponsiveModule();...sorry if my question is so dumb, i dont have engineering background education, so for me it is difficult to understand and I need a lot of research on every topic :p

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. The thing which you use is actually the object + its scope returned by the ResposiveModule function. Calling this method several times will return different objects.